# How to use the new dark theme on visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So, I am using visual studio community for a while now on my main PC. The last version I had was VS2017.

Then I got a brand new Laptop and also wanted to install VSCommunity, that's how I found out that there is already a 2019 edition. After I installed it, I immediately noticed the (I think) REALLY neat **new** dark theme.

Mostly because of that **new** dark theme (yeah I know it's ridiculous, but still), I decided to finally upgrade to VS2019 on my main PC. I removed *everything* that had to do with *any* earlier version of VS from my whole PC and then I installed VSCommunity 2019. After installing, it prompted me to log in with my visual studio account, which I did (I suppose that was the main mistake here). And boom, suddenly all of my previous color scheme preferences were recovered without prompting me (the settings were probably synced over my account).

This means basically that I my installed version of VS2019, which I wanted to install mostly because of the dark theme, does now not have the said **new** dark theme. **I tried to reset all settings and even set my color scheme to the default settings** (which worked) but the background and UI of the whole application still looks like it looked in VS2017 **with the old dark theme**, which I find very annoying.

Does anyone know how I can **make VS2019 use the new dark theme**? Thanks in advance.

(By the way: I did not log into my vs account on my laptop, that's probably why it worked)

Further information:

Yes, I have a dark theme selected in the settings. But as stated above, it resembles the **old** VS2017 dark theme. I also tried switching to a light theme and then back again; that didn't change anything

I did not configure any important settings in the new version, so if anyone could tell me how to *completely* reset *everything* in VS2019 (e.g. by deleting the folder that contains the infamous old dark theme) that would be enough. **BUT**: As I pointed out earlier, I already tried the "reset all settings" feature inside of VS2019, but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Syncing is a feature, you probably want to turn that off at least until this is resolved.  Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts.  The *probable* storage location for the active theme is c:\users\yourname\appdata\roaming\microsoft\visualstudio\16_xxxxx.  Not sure, I don't play with themes and don't have a file there that stores theming data.

Answer (score 5):

In *ANY* version of the Visual Studio, try:
`Tools->Options`
You should see:
`Environment->General` selected.
On the right side, on top:
`Visual experience`
`Color theme`
Just select `Dark` there.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, that didn't fix anything because the "dark" theme is already selected, but displays the old dark theme

Answer (score 3):

For anybody finding this via google (like I just did, even though it's a year late), the answer to the OP's question is `Tools -> Options` then `Text Editor / Basic / Advanced`. Scroll halfway down and choose **Visual Studio 2019** from the "Editor Color Scheme" dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Go to files=> preferences=>color theme=> select your theme ( dark theme is just fab... A person told that he likes dark themes and I started using that)

Answer (score 0):

You also can more the with this plugin 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio

It has some aesome theme including Material Design and Sumblime Material. It has more than 10 awesome themes.